# Can you recommend a book on the French Revolution?

Tags: france, revolution, french-empire

I pray this question doesn't get closed as too subjective. This is a site on history for goodness sake. What could be a more subjective topic??

Anyway, What i'd like is a recommendation of a book on the French Revolution. It seems a fascinating topic that unfolded in many directions with a lot of colorful characters involved. What I need is something that reads more like a novel and also relatively complete.

Any suggestions MUCH appreciated.
Thanks,
_Ramy

Comment: Alas, voted to close. The FAQ rules out "Asking for reference material" :(

Comment: But I can still upvote :)

Comment: As a biography for that period I highly recommend Caroline Moorehead's *Dancing to the Precipice: The Life of Lucie de la Tour du Pin, Eyewitness to an Era*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wikipedia page includes an extensive reference list of further reading:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_Revolution#Further_reading

Here is the reading list from USC's class [The Age of the French Revolution](http://dornsife.usc.edu/hist/spring-2013-course-descriptions/):

- Jeremy Popkin, *A Short History of the French Revolution*
- Laura Mason and Tracy Rizzo, eds., The French Revolution: A Document Collection
- Jean-Jacques Rousseau, *The Social Contract*
- RR Palmer, *Twelve Who Ruled*
- Laurent Dubois and John D. Garrigus, *Slave Rebellion in the Carribean, 1789-1804: A Brief History with Documents*
- David Bell, *The First Total War: Napoleon’s Europe and the Birth of Warfare as We Know It*